# JSoup scrape HTML document by attribute value

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to make a dynamic website and need some pics off the internet. I decided to scrape them off flickr and include the owners on my website but am running into problems scraping. I'll post part of the HTML below but if you want to check the source code yourself, here's the website. https://www.flickr.com/explore

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb ">            

    <span class="photo_container pc_ju">
        <a data-track="photo-click"  href="/photos/sheilarogers13/15586482942/in/explore-2014-10-20" title="Lake District" class="rapidnofollow photo-click"><img id="photo_img_15586482942" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3945/15586482942_6a7154363f_z.jpg"width="508" height="339" alt="Lake District" class="pc_img " border="0"><div class="play"></div></a>
    </span>
    <div class="meta">
        <div class="title"><a data-track="photo-click" href="/photos/sheilarogers13/15586482942/in/explore-2014-10-20" title="Lake District" class="title">Lake District</a></div>

        <div class="attribution-block">
            <span class="attribution">
                <span>by </span>
              ******<a data-track="owner" href="/photos/sheilarogers13" title="sheilarogers22" class="owner">sheilarogers22</a>******
            </span>
        </div>

        <span class="inline-icons">

                <a data-track="favorite" href="#" class="rapidnofollow fave-star-inline canfave" title="Add this photo to your favorites?"><img width="12" height="12" alt="[★]" src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/spaceball.gif" class="img"><span class="fave-count count">99+</span></a>
            <a title="Comments" href="#" class="rapidnofollow comments-icon comments-inline-btn">
                <img width="12" height="12" alt="Comments" src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/spaceball.gif">
                <span class="comment-count count">57</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-track="lightbox" class="rapidnofollow lightbox-inline" title="View in light box"><img width="12" height="12" alt="" src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/spaceball.gif"></a>
        </span>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I want the line where I put asterisks, in order to be able to give credit to the authors of the pictures.

My code:

```
Elements pgElem = doc.select("div.thumb").select("div.meta").select("[data-track]");
```

The above code however gives me all 4 data tracks in my div.meta though, and I only want the one that =owner.

I checked the JSoup documentation and it says that attributes with values are found using `[attr=value]`, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried:

`.select("[data-track=owner]")`

`.select("[data-track='owner']")`

but neither work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        Elements pgElem = doc.select("div.thumb").select("div.meta").select("[data-track]");
        Elements ownerElements = new Elements();
        for(Element element:pgElem){
            if(!element.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("data-track","owner").isEmpty()){
                ownerElements.add(element);
            }
        }
```

actually, I just gave it another spin and this works for me:

```
doc.select("div.thumb").select("div.meta").select("[data-track=owner]")
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the documentation says 
"[attr=value]: elements with attribute value, e.g. [width=500] (also quotable, like sequence")"
Is this for non-string attributes?

source: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax